# Why is the sampling distribution of normal distributed variable automatically also normal distributed

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, sampling

I am currently reading about the standard error. I know about central limit theorem, but I don't understand why, if my variable is normally distributed in the population, the sampling distribution (the distribution of the sample means) is also a normal distribution, no matter of sample size etc.

Answer (score 6):

This is not an asymptotic result, it is a finite-sample result and has nothing to do with the Central Limit Theorem.

You start by assuming that the population is normal. **The normal distribution is one of the few distributions that are closed under addition**, meaning that the sum of normal random variables follows a normal distribution (although with different parameters than the components of the sum). More over, scaling a normal random variable, leaves it a normal random variable (again, affecting the parametrization of it).
The sample mean of a sample from a normal population, is a sum of normal random variables, scaled by $1/n$. Hence it too follows a normal distribution.

The Central Limit Theorem comes into effect to lead to the same result asymptotically, when the population is not normally distributed.

Comment: +1 Because statistical language can be confusing, especially to beginners, I would like to point out that scaling *does* change the distribution: but it does not change its *shape* (which remains Normal) and that of course is what you are contending.

Comment: So very true. Corrected.

Comment: +1 Some people phrase it as 'scaling doesn't change the family of distributions', because the normal isn't so much a distribution as a location-scale family of distributions. (Don't take this as a suggested change to the answer, though, which seems fine as it is.)

Comment: @Glen_b Yes I have noticed that some times what is called "distribution" in one corner, is called "family of distributions" in another. I have the impression that the latter is used more by those that are more deeply into statistics.

Comment: @Alecos I use them both, so I'm not even consistent, though most times it's clear enough. In a situation like that, where one wants to say "the same <something>" it does seem to reduce the chance of confusion.

Comment: @Glen_b Yeah, I think you 're right, choice of words should and does depend on context, most of the times.

Comment: Are we assuming the normal RVs being added are independent and/or uncorrelated?

Comment: @MSIS Either that they are independent, or that they are dependent but follow jointly a multivariate Normal. The standard example is $X$ and $Y = -X$. If $X$ is Normal, so is $Y$, but $X +Y = 0$, a degenerate r.v. Moreover $(X,Y)$ do not follow jointly a multivariate Normal.